# How to add a dollar sign to the input at the beginning in Material UI?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Some Dollar Amount</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Some Dollar Amount" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKGU.png)

Comment: Help you fix what??

Comment: I am looking for some code so that I can design the input as shown in the image( please check the link)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the matPrefix attribute and then styling it?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Some Dollar Amount</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Some Dollar Amount" required>
  <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Material Form Fields](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples)